# Username and password exist but not found and authenticated

Tags: java, mysql, swing

The password and username are retrieved from the database. If one row is returned, a user exists. However, the below code says that the user does not exist even if the username and password are correct.

```
if(con != null) {
    try {
        String query = "select * from users where username = '"+user.getText()+"' and password = '"+pasword.getText()+"'";
        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(query);

        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        int count = 0;

        while(rs.next()) {
            count = count + 1;
        }

        if(count == 1) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "user exist");
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "user doesnot exist");
        }

        rs.close();
        ps.close();
    } catch (Exception e1) {
    }
}
```

Comment: did u checked user.getText() & pasword.getText() values? r they really exists in DB or not?

Comment: `} catch (Exception e1){

    }`  Don't ignore error output!  Change that to (at the least) `} catch (Exception e1){
e1.printStackTrace();
    }`

Comment: That code is ripe for sql injection.

Comment: No point in using a `PreparedStatement` as you're not taking advantage of the functionality the API provides. See [Using Prepared Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) for how it should be used.  If you're going to count the matches, then why not just use `select count(*) from ...` instead?

Answer (score 0):

It´s a sensible code, but you should to write the

```
e.printStackTrace()
```

in the catch block, maybe an exception it's occurs. Check the `user.getText()` and  `password.getText()` content, also you can apply an `user.getText().trim()` for example, to delete de blank spaces. Then try this:

```
while(rs.next()) {
        count++;
}

if(count > 0) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "user exist");
} else {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "user doesnot exist");
}
```

Good luck!